# Check for ascending order of a list in Racket

Tags: recursion, scheme, lisp, racket

I'm new to racket and trying to write a function that checks if a list is in strictly ascending order.

'( 1 2 3) would return true
'(1 1 2) would return false (repeats)
'(3 2 4) would return false

**My code so far is:**
[Image of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVyai.png)

```
(define (ascending? 'list)
   (if (or (empty? list) (= (length 'list) 1)) true
      (if (> first (first (rest list))) false
          (ascending? (rest list)))))
```

I'm trying to call ascending? recursively where my base case is that the list is empty or has only 1 element (then trivially ascending).

I keep getting an error message when I use check-expect that says "application: not a procedure."

Comment: Please don’t post images of code; put your code in the actual question.

Comment: Okay, just posted it above!!

Answer (score 3):

I guess you want to implement a procedure from scratch, and Alexander's answer is spot-on. But in true functional programming style, you should try to reuse existing procedures to write the solution. This is what I mean:

```
(define (ascending? lst)
  (apply < lst))
```

It's shorter, simpler and easier to understand. And it works as expected!

```
(ascending? '(1 2 3))
=> #t

(ascending? '(1 1 2))
=> #f
```

Comment: looks   beautiful :)

Answer (score 2):

Some things to consider when writing functions:

- Avoid using built in functions as variable names. For example, `list` is a built in procedure that returns a newly allocated list, so don't use it as an argument to your function, or as a variable. A common convention/alternative is to use `lst` as a variable name for lists, so you could have `(define (ascending? lst) ...)`.
- Don't quote your variable names. For example, you would have `(define lst '(1 2 3 ...))` and not `(define 'lst '(1 2 3 ...))`.
- If you have multiple conditions to test (ie. more than 2), it may be cleaner to use [`cond`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/if.html?q=cond#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fletstx-scheme..rkt%29._cond%29%29) rather than nesting multiple `if` statements.

To fix your implementation of `ascending?` (after replacing `'list`), note on line 3 where you have `(> first (first (rest list)))`. Here you are comparing `first` with `(first (rest list))`, but what you really want is to compare `(first lst)` with `(first (rest lst))`, so it should be `(>= (first lst) (first (rest lst)))`.

Here is a sample implementation:

```
(define (ascending? lst)
  (cond
    [(null? lst) #t]
    [(null? (cdr lst)) #t]
    [(>= (car lst) (cadr lst)) #f]
    [else
     (ascending? (cdr lst))]))
```

or if you want to use `first/rest` and `true/false` you can do:

```
(define (ascending? lst)
  (cond
    [(empty? lst) true]
    [(empty? (rest lst)) true]
    [(>= (first lst) (first (rest lst))) false]
    [else
     (ascending? (rest lst))]))
```

For example,

```
> (ascending? '(1 2 3))
#t
> (ascending? '(1 1 2))
#f
> (ascending? '(3 2 4))
#f
```

Comment: Great, the cond makes a lot more sense than the nested ifs.  And thanks for the other tips as well!!

Answer (score 0):

This Scheme solution uses an explicitly recursive *named `let`* and [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization):

```scm
(define (ascending? xs)
   (if (null? xs) #t                    ; Edge case: empty list
      (let asc? ((x (car xs))           ; Named `let`
                 (xs' (cdr xs)) )
         (if (null? xs') #t
            (let ((x' (car xs')))       ; Memoization of `(car xs)`
               (if (< x x')
                  (asc? x' (cdr xs'))   ; Tail recursion
                  #f))))))              ; Short-circuit termination

(display
   (ascending?
      (list 1 1 2) ))                   ; `#f`
```

Answer (score 0):

If you write down the properties of an ascending list in bullet form;

An ascending list is either

- the empty list, *or*
- a one-element list, *or*
- a list where

  - the first element is smaller than the second element, *and*
  - the tail of the list is ascending

you can wind up with a pretty straight translation:

```
(define (ascending? ls)
  (or (null? ls)
      (null? (rest ls))
      (and (< (first ls) (first (rest ls)))
           (ascending? (rest ls)))))
```